# How to enable gui in gazebo when the simulation is running?

Tags: gazebo-gui

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am setting the gui flag false when I bring up the robot model using roslaunch in gazebo. My code interacts with the robot model to apply a torque at each joint. After a while, with the code and gazebo simulation still running, I want to turn the gui back on. Is there any way to accomplish this? Please explain. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14093/how-to-enable-gui-in-gazebo-when-the-simulation-is-running?/) by [SP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2519/sp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In a terminal use the 'gzclient' command.

---

Originally posted by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) with karma: 284 on 2016-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2519/sp/) on 2016-08-15**:
Thank you for the simple and awesome solution.